# How to proof that $\left|x - y\right| + \left|y - z\right| \geq \left|x - z\right|$, where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, measure-theory, inequality, metric-spaces, roots

I am not a professional mathematician and I recently started studying math as a hobby. Intuitively this result is true. My intuition is the distance from x to y plus the distance from y to z cannot be strictly less than the distance from x to z. However, I have no idea how to prove this proposition.

$$\left|x - y\right| + \left|y - z\right| \geq \left|x - z\right|, \forall x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Ever heard of the triangle inequality?

Comment: hint: $|x-z|=|x-y+y-z|$

Comment: Simply use the definition of the absolute value.

Comment: @JohnK no, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!!!